# Applescript from PackageMaker

Tags: macos, applescript, packagemaker, mpkg

This is my first time using packagemaker. Basically, I need to copy some files to some folder, and then open photoshop and load a .atn file. I have the applescript written but how can I execute this applescript from package maker?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it from inside a bash script.

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947925/add-app-to-osx-login-items-during-a-package-maker-installer-postflight-script) for details.